# configure dhcp client without accepting nameserver entries

Tags: opensuse, dns, dhcp

I am trying to configre my openSuSE 12.1 machine as DHCP client, but especially do not want it to set the name server entries to `/etc/resolv.conf` it has got from DHCP server.

Can I do it on the client site without manually deleting the entries afterwards?

On windows machines this is possible due to the setting

> (   ) Obtain DNS server address automatically
>
> (O) Use the following DNS server addresses:

and then just leave the fields for Preferred and Alternate DNS server blank.

Answer (score 3):

Add to your /etc/dhclient.conf:

```
supersede domain-name-servers HERE_THE_DNS_SERVER_IP;
```

Comment: sorry, but the file `/etc/dhclient.conf`doesn't exists, instead I found another dhcp-client config file `/etc/sysconfig/network/dhcp`. I tried to add your line to it, but even after invoking `/sbin/SuSEconfig` again, the entries still remain in my resolf.conf... I also tried to set void nameservers in YaST (e.g. 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2 & 127.0.0.3), but the client still sets it's search domain to the one gotten from DHCP server...

Comment: Does setting NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS in /etc/sysconfig/network/config help?

Answer (score 0):

Modify or add the line `PEERDNS=no` to the configuration file that corresponds with your network interface in the directory `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

If your network device is `eth0`, the file to modify will be named `ifcfg-eth0`.

To find the name of your network interface use the command `ip address show` to list your network interfaces and their addresses.

Additionally, you can specify the DNS entries that you want to have appear in `/etc/resolv.conf` by adding the lines `DNS1=<ip-address>` and `DNS2=<ip-address>` to the network configuration file.

https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_manconf.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html